# Pod CPU Throttling

Tags: kubernetes

I'm experiencing a **strange issue** when using **CPU Requests/Limits in Kubernetes**. Prior to setting any CPU Requests/Limits at all, all my services performed very well. I recently started placing some Resource Quotas to avoid future resource starvation. These values were set based in the actual usage of those services, but to my surprise, after those were added, some **services started to increase their response time drastically**. My first guess was that I might placed wrong Requests/Limits, but looking at the metrics revealed that in fact **none of the services facing this issue were near those values**. In fact, some of them were closer to the Requests than the Limits.

Then I started looking at CPU throttling metrics and found that **all my pods are being throttled**. I then increased the limits for one of the services to 1000m (from 250m) and I saw less throttling in that pod, but I don't understand why I should set that higher limit if the pod wasn't reaching its old limit (250m).

So my question is: **If I'm not reaching the CPU limits, why are my pods throttling? Why is my response time increasing if the pods are not using their full capacity?**

Here there are some screenshots of my metrics **(CPU Request: 50m, CPU Limit: 250m)**:

**CPU Usage (here we can see the CPU of this pod never reached its limit of 250m):**
[image: CPU Usage]

**CPU Throttling:**
[image: CPU Throttling]

**After setting limits to this pod to *1000m*, we can observe less throttling**
[image: Comparation]

**kubectl top**

[image: Top]

P.S: Before setting these Requests/Limits there wasn't throttling at all (as expected)

P.S 2: None of my nodes are facing high usage. In fact, none of them are using more than 50% of CPU at any time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How you obtained cpu throttling graph?

Answer (score 43):

If you see the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#how-pods-with-resource-limits-are-run) you see when you issue a `Request` for CPUs it actually uses the [`--cpu-shares`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cpu-share-constraint) option in Docker which actually uses the cpu.shares attribute for the [cpu,cpuacct cgroup](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/sec-cpu_and_memory-use_case) on Linux. So a value of `50m` is about `--cpu-shares=51` based on the maximum being `1024`.  `1024` represents 100% of the shares, so `51` would be 4-5% of the share.  That's pretty low, to begin with.  But the important factor here is that this relative to how many pods/container you have on your system and what cpu-shares those have (are they using the default).

So let's say that on your node you have another pod/container with 1024 shares which is the default and you have this pod/container with 4-5 shares. Then this container will get about get about 0.5% CPU, while the other  pod/container will
get about 99.5% of the CPU (if it has no limits). So again it all depends on how many pods/container you have on the node and what their shares are.

Also, not very well documented in the [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#how-pods-with-resource-limits-are-run), but if you use `Limit` on a pod it's basically using two flags in Docker: [`--cpu-period and --cpu--quota`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cpu-period-constraint) which actually uses the cpu.cfs_period_us and the cpu.cfs_quota_us attributes for the [cpu,cpuacct cgroup](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/sec-cpu_and_memory-use_case) on Linux. This was introduced to the fact that cpu.shares didn't provide a limit so you'd spill over cases where containers would grab most of the CPU.

So, as far as this limit is concerned you will never hit it if you have other containers on the same node that don't have limits (or higher limits) but have a higher cpu.shares because they will end up optimizing and picking idle CPU. This could be what you are seeing, but again depends on your specific case.

A longer explanation for all of the above [here](https://medium.com/@betz.mark/understanding-resource-limits-in-kubernetes-cpu-time-9eff74d3161b).

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. I might not getting something. Above you said that 50m is a pretty low value. While I agree with that, the metrics above show that 50m is the actual usage of that pod, so why I would request more cpu time for it? I will check if I left some containers without requests/limits configured though. Can you clarify?

Comment: It's `50m` because that's what you requested so that a minimum value (4-5% of the CPU), but there could be other pods that are getting `1000m` or `1024m` which would make the `50m` the max even if you have a `Limit` defined.

Comment: I like your explanation, but I'm running 106 pods on a five-node cluster. Each Node has 4 cores, so there is a total capacity of 20000m. That means that if containers by default request 1024m I could only schedule 20 pods. Also, the kubernetes dashboard show that there is only 25%-50% of CPU requested. It shouldn't be something like 100% in that case?

Comment: I checked and I have some pods without limits set. I think I could test setting a Resource Quota on the namespace to limit all the pods there

Comment: Yes. If they don't have limits they may spill over in terms of minimum cpu shares.

Comment: Ok, i will check that! Thanks

Comment: That might explain why my applications ran faster prior to setting those requests and limits

Comment: What I dont understand is why the pod performed better when I increased its limit. If other pods on the cluster were preventing the pod to use more than 50m, why there was less throttling when I increased the limits (and not the requests)?

Comment: I think it all depends on what the limits and pods were for the other pods at the time when you specifically upped the limit. Did you change the limit or the request to 1000m?

Comment: I observe similar issue. I my case default cpu limits / requests are set in LimitRange, they are overriden by deployment. Cpu limits / requests are not set in namespace's ResourceQuota. My pod is not even close to declared limits / requests. During research I found an issue on github: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/67577

Comment: @PiotrB I wrote an answer below explaining why this can happen

Answer (score 31):

Kubernetes uses (Completely Fair Scheduler) CFS quota to enforce CPU limits on pod containers. See "How does the CPU Manager work" described in https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/24/feature-highlight-cpu-manager/ for further details.

The CFS is a Linux feature, added with the 2.6.23 kernel, which is based on two parameters: cpu.cfs_period_us and cpu.cfs_quota
To visualize these two parameters, I'd like to borrow the following picture from Daniele Polencic from his excellent blog (https://twitter.com/danielepolencic/status/1267745860256841731):

[image]

If you configure a CPU limit in K8s it will set period and quota. If a process running in a container reaches the limit it is preempted and has to wait for the next period. It is throttled.
So this is the effect, which you are experiencing. The period and quota algorithm should not be considered to be a CPU limit, where processes are unthrottled, if not reached.
The behavior is confusing, and also a K8s issue exist for this: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/67577
The recommendation given in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/51135 is to not set CPU limits for pods that shouldn't be throttled.

Answer (score 7):

TLDR: remove your CPU limits. ([Unless this alert fires on `metrics-server` in which case that wont work.](https://github.com/robusta-dev/alert-explanations/wiki/CPUThrottlingHigh-on-metrics-server-(Prometheus-alert))) CPU limits are actually a bad-practice and not a best-practice.

### Why this happens

I'll focus on what to do, but first let me give a quick example showing why this happens:

1. Imagine a pod with a CPU limit of 100m which is equivalent to 1/10 vCPU.
2. The pod does nothing for 10 minutes.
3. Then it uses the CPU nonstop for 200ms. The usage during the burst is equivalent to 2/10 vCPU, hence the pod is over it's limit and will be throttled.
4. On the other hand, the average CPU usage will be incredibly low.

In a case like this you'll be throttled but the burst is so small (200 milliseconds) that it wont show up in any graphs.

### What to do

You actually don't want CPU limits in most cases because they prevent pods from using spare resources. There are Kubernetes maintainers on the record saying you shouldn't use CPU limits and should only set requests.

### More info

I wrote a whole wiki page on [why CPU throttling can occur despite low CPU usage and what to do about it](https://github.com/robusta-dev/alert-explanations/wiki/CPUThrottlingHigh-(Prometheus-Alert)#why-cpu-throttling-can-occur-despite-low-cpu-usage-permalink). I also go into some common edge cases like how to deal with this for `metrics-server` which doesn't follow the usual rules.

Comment: One problem with removing CPU limits is that you can only get a QoS of "Guaranteed" if you have matching cpu request/limits (along with matching memory request/limits): https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/quality-service-pod/

Comment: @erewok to the best of my knowledge the QoS doesn't impact anything other than oom_kill_adjust

Comment: Funny you should say that: I have been researching QoS this week and haven't found a lot of information on what a "Guaranteed" QoS truly provides. Do you know of any resources on this? The official k8s docs seemed limited in this area.

Comment: @erewok I'm going to compile everything I know and research into a blog post for https://home.robusta.dev/blog - no specific date for releasing the post yet, but hopefully will be soon

Comment: I finally discovered the answer to this: if you change the CPU-management-policy to "static" then a "Guaranteed" QoS with an integer-cpu *really does* guarantee a dedicated quantity of cores. See: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/cpu-management-policies/#static-policy-options